# Json output from Vegeta HTTP load testing

Tags: http, command-line-interface, load-testing, vegeta

I am using Vegeta to make some stress test but I am having some trouble while generating a json report. Running the following command I am able to see text results:

vegeta attack -targets="./vegeta_sagemaker_True.txt" -rate=10 -duration=2s | vegeta report -output="attack.json" -type=text

```
Requests      [total, rate]            20, 10.52
Duration      [total, attack, wait]    2.403464884s, 1.901136s, 502.328884ms
Latencies     [mean, 50, 95, 99, max]  945.385864ms, 984.768025ms, 1.368113304s, 1.424427549s, 1.424427549s
Bytes In      [total, mean]            5919, 295.95
Bytes Out     [total, mean]            7104, 355.20
Success       [ratio]                  95.00%
Status Codes  [code:count]             200:19  400:1  
Error Set:
400
```

When I run the same command changing -type-text to -type=json I receive really weird numbers ad they don't make sense for me:

```
{
  "latencies": {
    "total": 19853536952,
    "mean": 992676847,
    "50th": 972074984,
    "95th": 1438787021,
    "99th": 1636579198,
    "max": 1636579198
  },
  "bytes_in": {
    "total": 5919,
    "mean": 295.95
  },
  "bytes_out": {
    "total": 7104,
    "mean": 355.2
  },
  "earliest": "2019-04-24T14:32:23.099072+02:00",
  "latest": "2019-04-24T14:32:25.00025+02:00",
  "end": "2019-04-24T14:32:25.761337546+02:00",
  "duration": 1901178000,
  "wait": 761087546,
  "requests": 20,
  "rate": 10.519793517492838,
  "success": 0.95,
  "status_codes": {
    "200": 19,
    "400": 1
  },
  "errors": [
    "400 "
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know why this should be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: By "really weird numbers", do you mean the numbers in the `latencies` field?

Comment: @shaochuancs exactly! And duration for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These numbers are nanoseconds -- the internal representation of `time.Duration` in Go.

For example, the `latencies.mean` in the JSON is `992676847`, which means 992676847 nanoseconds, that is 992676847/1000/1000 = 992.676847ms.

Actually, in vegeta, if you declare `type` as `text` (`-type=text`), it will use [NewTextReporter](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/blob/master/lib/reporters.go#L56), and print the `time.Duration` as a user-friendly string. If you declare `type` as `json` (`-type=json`), it will use [NewJSONReporter](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/blob/master/lib/reporters.go#L107) and return [time.Duration](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration)'s internal representation:

> A Duration represents the elapsed time between two instants as an int64 nanosecond count. The representation limits the largest representable duration to approximately 290 years.